# Unit test karma with browser phantomJS doesn't support import inheritance

Tags: inheritance, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I met this issue when unit testing with phantomjs. That's I think the browser phantomjs doesn't support import inheritance. Here is the issue detail:

Environment:

- karma 1.5.0
- phantomjs: 2.1.1 (using as browser)

And I have these model classes:

***base.model.ts***

```
export class BaseModel {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
}
```

***customer.model.ts***

```
import { BaseModel  } from './base.model';

export class CustomerModel extends  BaseModel {
    address?: string;
    // more properties defined
}
```

***home.model.ts***

```
import { BaseModel  } from './base.model';
import { CustomerModel } from './customer.model';

export class HomeModel extends  BaseModel {
    param1: CustomerModel;

    constructor(data?: any) { // write some logic in here }
}
```

***home.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Home } from './home.model';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    constructor(){  }

    get() {
        let home = new HomeModel();
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce the behaviour**

1. Write the unit test for function get() of HomeService
   (home.service.ts)
2. Run the unit test: `npm run test` will excute `karma start config/karma.conf.js`

**Error**

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) 
>   ERROR TypeError: undefined: can't set as prototype!

**Root cause**:
After days of investigating, I have found that the issue just happend when unit test going through `new HomeModel()`. And then its related to the `BaseModel` with `extends`, I think when we `new HomeModel()`, it initialized the the `BaseModel` first (import will run from top to bottom), then `CustomerModel` is initialized after that. In `CustomerModel`, it still have import `BaseModel` to `extends`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced with the same problem with `"typescript": "2.4.0"`:

Updated the following dependencies and it's helped:

```
"@types/core-js": "0.9.42",
"html-loader": "^0.5.1",
"jasmine": "^2.7.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.7.0",
"karma": "^1.7.0",
"karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
```